# MS Graph - On Demand MFA

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm just learning MS Graph and need to basically make a button on a web page trigger an MFA request through MS Authenticator so that an agent can confirm identity. I've been looking through the API docs but can't seem to find what I need. Is this possible through Graph or should I be looking elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not possible with MS Graph.

Any type of MFA can only be triggered during the authentication process.

There is a way to trigger MFA only for specific high privileged operations with the aid of Conditional Access - you can read more about it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/developer-guide-conditional-access-authentication-context

But using a pure API approach, like the one you described, is not possible.